# If Hashtable<E, ?>.containsKey(Object o) returns true for a certain object, am I safe to cast that Object to E?

Tags: java, collections, casting, hashtable

For example, if I am implementing my own `Collection<E>` that uses a `Hashtable<E, Integer>` as its underlying data structure, I will implement `remove(Object o)`, but `o` is not an `E`, it's an `Object`. But, if it returns true for `containsKey(o)`, then am I safe to assume that casting `o` to `E` is going to succeed?

```
@Override
public boolean remove (@NotNull final Object o)
{
    if(underlyingHashTable.containsKey(o))
    {
        @NotNull final E item = (E) o;
        
    }
}
```

The IDE highlights the cast to `(E) o` as unchecked but I'm wondering if my assumption is sane & safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not strictly safe, even though, as you guess, it's *usually* fine.

For example, if you had a `Hashtable<LinkedList<String>, Integer>`, and did `containsKey(myArrayList)`, it could return true -- because it's legal for `LinkedList.equals(ArrayList)` to return `true` (and, in fact, it's mandated by the `List` interface).

(This is among the reasons that `Map.get` takes an `Object`, not a `K`.)